# Show Image in ImmersiveSpace

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos, visionos-simulator

I'm playing around with `VisionOS` and wondered if it's possible to display an Image in `ImmersiveSpace`.                From the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/ImmersiveSpace

I see a way to create `ImmersiveSpace` but it's not clear how can I encapsulate an Image inside of it (and let users see it as an immersive experience).

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can display anything, I suggest looking at Destination Video tutorial. But all the tutorials will likely be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render an image in an immersive space, load an image as a texture, create a material with that texture, and attach a model component with that material to an entity inside RealityView. The code will look something like this:

```
 var body: some View {
   ZStack {
      RealityView { content in
         
         // Load the texture
         guard let texture = try? Texture.load(named: "sampleImage", in: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load texture.")
         }
         
         // Create unlit material
         var material = UnlitMaterial()
         
         // Set properties
         material.color = .white
         material.texture = texture
         
         
         let entity = Entity()
         entity.components.set(ModelComponent(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 1, height: 1), materials: [material]))
         
         
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any chance you offer a paid consultant, code-wise? We need a bit of help in our structure which is a bit bigger then a SOV question